# Rewrite a URL while resetting a request header - nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to rewrite a relative URL "/A" to "/B", while also setting the request header. The url /A is already exposed to some clients. /B is essentially /A with the Accept header set to "json". I am trying to remove /A support from the upstream and just have /B in the upstream. But I need to continue to support /A. Hence the problem

I am able to rewrite successfully however the header does not get set.

```
location = /A {
   proxy_set_header Accept "json"
   rewrite /A /B;
}

location = /B {
  ... a lot of configurations here ...
  proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
}
```

The following works for me, but I see that nginx makes an additional request to itself which is not so cool.

```
location = /A {
   proxy_set_header Accept "json"
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$server_port/B;
}

location = /B {
  ... a lot of configurations here ...
  proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your question would be more effective if you would explain why you are doing this.

Comment: I have a URL /A already exposed to some clients. /B is essentially /A with the Accept header set correctly. I am trying to remove /A support from the upstream and just have /B in the upstream. But I need to continue to support /A. Hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location = /A {
   set $accept "json";
   rewrite /A /B;
}

location = /B {
    proxy_set_header Accept $accept;
    ... a lot of configurations here ...
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
}
```

nginx won't set the header at all if an empty string passed as `proxy_set_header` second parameter. And if your request will not be captured by `location = /A` block, `$accept` variable would have an empty value at `location = /B` block.

**Update**

Configuration given above will clear an `Accept` HTTP header if the request is captured by the second location block. If you want to preserve it, you can use more complex configuration:

```
map $accept $accept_header {
    ""       $http_accept;
    default  $accept;
}

server {

    ...

    location = /A {
        set $accept "json";
        rewrite /A /B;
    }

    location = /B {
        proxy_set_header Accept $accept_header;
        ... a lot of configurations here ...
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: What is wrong about setting the header in the location /A {} block ? Could you please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: nginx config is not a programming language, there are many caveats you can get into. For example, you should have all the upstream config in the same block where your `proxy_pass` directive is located. The order of this upstream configuration directives is also does not matter, you can place `proxy_pass` directive before the `proxy_set_header` and this won't change nginx behavior. I tested this solution and it works, the header is passed to the upstream, look for an error in some other place. Maybe it should be `application/json` or `text/json` instead of `json`?

Comment: @vikasap Found some issues while testing, see the update.

Comment: There was an issue in my --- lot of configurations here .., but yes I ended up using the map as well and got this to work. Thank you @Ivan